# Is there a keyboard shortcut to target my companion?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In SWTOR, I often find myself playing a healer to my companion tanking, especially against Elite-level mobs.

Currently, I am pressing F1 twice in order to target my companion. Sometimes, though, I don't quite make it and poor Khem Val dies.

Is there a single shortcut I can use to avoid this?

Comment: Also, consider using the "focus" system.

Comment: @DavidB: Could you elaborate on what the focus system is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default the key combination to do this is Shift + F1.

Answer (score 5):

While the default key combination to target your companion is Shift + F1, you might also be interested in learning about the focus system so you can quickly heal primary healing targets in many situations.

---

A focus is like a secondary target.  To set focus, first target something, then press Alt-F.  Now you may target something else.  If you want to switch your target and your focus, press Alt-F again (trivia, not how this is normally used).

Now you have a focus, but to use hotkeys on it you must go to:

```
preferences -> controls -> enable focus target
```

Once you've done that, you may use the focus-modifier-key (`end` by default) to use abilities on your focus instead of your target.